# Index error list page out of range on danbooru twitter bot

Tags: python

i am using a code that i found in github, i had to modify somethings, it works, but sometimes (even when working) it gives Index error page out of range and then stop working.

> File "bot.py", line 36, in module
>       imageSource = pageTable[arrayNum]["file_url"]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Here is my code

```
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                        
import requests                                                                                                                                                                                                    
import tweepy                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import urllib                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import os                                                                                                                                                                                                          
import random                                                                                                                                                                                                      

page = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                           

url = 'https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts.json?tags=shimakaze_(kantai_collection) rating:s&limit=1000&page='                                                                                                         

consumer_key = ''                                                                                                                                                                         
consumer_secret = ''                                                                                                                                             
access_key = ''                                                                                                                                                  
access_secret = ''                                                                                                                                                    

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)                                                                                                                                                          
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)                                                                                                                                                                   

api = tweepy.API(auth)                                                                                                                                                                                             

while True:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        try:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                random.seed()                                                                                                                                                                                      
                jsURL = url + str(random.randint(1,1000))                                                                                                                                                          
                response = requests.get(jsURL)                                                                                                                                                                     
                pageTable = response.json()                                                                                                                                                                        
                arrayNum = random.randint(0,5)                                                                                                                                                                     

                print arrayNum                                                                                                                                                                                     
                imageSource = pageTable[arrayNum]["file_url"]                                                                                                                                                      
                imageURL = imageSource                                                                                                                                                                             
                print imageURL                                                                                                                                                                                     
                sourceURL = "http://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/" + str(pageTable[arrayNum]["id"])                                                                                                                    
                print sourceURL                                                                                                                                                                                    
                urllib.urlretrieve(imageURL, 'image.jpg')                                                                                                                                                          

                .                                                                                                                                                
                tweetString = sourceURL + " "                                                                                                                                                                      
                api.update_with_media('image.jpg', status=tweetString)                                                                                                                                             

                os.remove('image.jpg')                                                                                                                                                                             
               post. Limited to 500 requests/hour.                                                                                                     
                time.sleep(600)                                                                                                                                                                                    

        except tweepy.error.TweepError:                                                                                                                                                                            
                print "Image too large, finding a different image.."
```

`arrayNum = random.randint(0,5)` line gives the error, that code generates a 0 - 5 numbers, and use as danbooru page, so i don't know why it gives an IndexError

Comment: According to the error the line `imageSource = pageTable[arrayNum]["file_url"] ` is causing the error.  You need to check the length of the array to ensure `arrayNum` is not out of bounds.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the response you get maybe empty sometimes. I've tried (which can be a possibility within your random range)

https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts.json?tags=shimakaze_(kantai_collection)%20rating:s&limit=1000&page=796

and get a response with empty list. So calling on an index with empty list will give you the index error. Check if the response is not empty.